# Firebase federated identity control flow

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am making a web app where I need to provide federated identity login(google, facebook) feature.

At backend there will be auth server whose job will be to verify the accessToken that client gets from these providers(google, fb) and generate a custom jwt token and send it to client. This new jwt token client will be sending to server for authentication and authorization.

In summary the flow will look like -- (*please refer image attached*)

**Two things I wanted to confirm**

1. Whether the flow that I have thought of is the way federated identity support works? Am I correct
2. The custom jwtToken() that I will be generating will be via

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance(firebaseApp).createCustomToken();
```

but there is no way for verifying this customToken() at firebase.[image: auth flow that I am planning to build for my app]

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for sharing the link. I have referred to this link earlier for verifying the idToken.
Two things on which I need your expert advice is
1. Should we generate custom jwtToken(access token) for interaction between client and backend server for further communication? 
2. If yes then using firebase `createCustomToken()` because there is no method provided by firebase to later verify this custom token and i then need to verify this token manually.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Doesn't the method described in the link allow you to verify the tokens in your #2? If not, can you show what you tried and what error you get?

Comment: Above link mentions about verifyIdToken(). I am looking to how to verifyCustomToken(). this I am not able to get on firebase doc

Comment: **com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: verifyIdToken() expects an ID token, but was given a custom token. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token**. 

getting above exception when validating trying to validate customToken with verifyIdToken() method. this is incorrect I know but similar method I am in search of to verify custom token or need firebase public key of token generation to do custom verification

Comment: Hmm... I thought you'd get an ID token again after signing in with the custom token, but I must admit it's been quite some time since I used that sign-in flow. :-/ --- I hope somebody else knows how to do this.